# Removing repeated field items

Tags: 6, ajax, entities

I'm using [Flexifield](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) to create a repeating series of CCK field groups via a button that says "Add another item" (I.e., setting the number of field values to unlimited). See below:

[image: Add another item button in conjunction with flexifield content rows.]

My client has requested the ability to remove rows from this list once added. Any idea how I'd do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't worked w/ Flexifield, but CCK's Multigroup feature (you can find it in the 6.x-3.x branch) has what you're looking for.

Comment: That would require quite a lot of re-development; I'm pretty tied to Flexifield at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/291864) that does exactly what I was asking for. Problem solved!